# Why is base64 encoding my file on a Mac not resulting in a proper base64 string?

Tags: string, bash, macos, encoding, base64

I'm using Mac OS 10.13.3.  I'm trying to base64 encode a binary file but am having some issues.  Specifically, I thought all base64 encoded files have to have a length that is a multiple of 4.  However, when I encode my file, notice taht the length is not divisible by 4 ...

```
localhost:lib davea$ openssl base64 -in myfile.binary -out ~/Downloads/myfile.base64
localhost:lib davea$ ls -al ~/Downloads/myfile.base64 
-rw-r--r-- 1 davea staff 93162 May 31 14:22 /Users/davea/Downloads/myfile.base64
```

Also when I look at the contents of the base64 file, I don't see the traditional "=" or "==" at the end, which usually indicates padding

```
localhost:lib davea$ cat ~/Downloads/myfile.base64
...
C9vgMjoKSQYkXMLTrGKRleR558g3bY3VTqlsVvTqZXquCLp4JS4cprTG6N10H0u9
i4pwPrVmSAP2DmE1V7mGwR2e4fiYEWnZjpSbHofpzlUo34yhiQ2/5kJoQZktD7BU
uxYBAgQIECBAgBs2
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to base64 encode my file?

Comment: Your file size is not what you expect because you are not taking into account the line ending characters in the file.  Every 48 characters in the input file is going to have 64 characters of output + a carriage return or line feed depending on which system you do it on.  Also there is a line ending character on the last line regardless.  So the file size should always be a multiple of 4 after subtracting `ceiling( length_of_input_file / 48 )` or `ceiling( length_of_output_file / 64 )`

Comment: Hi @Jason, The reason I ask is because when I try and decode my file using a JS library (https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js/), the library is complaining about the fact that my file length is not a mutiple of four, which makes sense given what I listed .  So what's the proper way to see the length of the base64-encoded string?

Comment: My calculation is incorrect in my first comment.  Should be:  ...multiple of 4 after subtracting `ceiling( length_of_input_file / 76 )` or `ceiling( length_of_output_file / 64 )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK.  I believe we were over thinking this quite a bit.  Here is what you are looking for to get the desired behavior:

`openssl base64 -A -in myfile.binary -out ~/Downloads/myfile.base64`

This will convert to base64 without any line endings.  The `-A` option is what does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong,

No

> or is there another way to base64 encode my file?

Yes, you can use `base64`. It takes a parameter to specify line length but is otherwise similar, the equivalent to your command is:

```
base64 -b 64 -i myfile.binary -o ~/Downloads/myfile.base64
```

> Also when I look at the contents of the base64 file, I don't see the traditional "=" or "==" at the end, which usually indicates padding

Base64 maps 3 input bytes to 4 output bytes. Your file is 93162 bytes which is divisible by 3, so no padding required.

HTH

Comment: I'm getting an "base64: invalid option -- 'b'" error when I run the above command.  I tried it on both MacOS X and Cent OS 7.

Comment: Hmmm, must be a problem with my system.  I'll have to investigate it further.